# Periodic Function as a Convolution

Tags: convolution, signal-processing, periodic-functions

I am reading a book about Signals and there is an exercise asking:
Show that any periodic function can be written as the convolution of a non-periodic function with a train of Dirac delta distributions.
Train here meaning a sum of the form:
$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n \delta(x-na)
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f$ be a periodic function of period $a>0$.

Now, consider $g$ to be the function that coincides with  $f$ on $[0, a)$, and is $0$ anywhere else. $g$ is non-periodic, unless $f=0$. Then you can verify that for all $x$, $$f(x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}g(x-na)=\left (g \ast \sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}\delta_{na}\right)(x)$$

Comment: Thank you. So basically we use the $\delta_{na}$'s to staple copies of the original period where they are needed.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it.